# How to create a custom athorization attribute in asp.net mvc5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two entity sets like below:

```
public class Serial
    {
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)]
        public int SerialID { get; set; }
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please provide your membership serial")]
        [StringLength(16,ErrorMessage="This field can't be longer as of 16 characters.")]
        public string UserSerial { get; set; }
    }
```

**AND**

```
public class Subscription
    {
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)]
        public int SubscriptionID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please provide a subscription code.")]
        public string AdminSerial { get; set; }
    }
```

I would like to create a custom authorization attribute to design my action methods within my controllers with following scenario:

> I would like to check if the any value of `UserSerial` in Serial
>   Entity not equal to any value of`AdminSerial` in Subscription Entity.
>   If the above condition become true so the `ActionResult` method itself should be executed else the Custom `AuthorizeAttribute` should redirect it to another action method, here is what i tried but it isn't working am i missing something?

```
public class RequireSerial : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        EFDbContext db = new EFDbContext();
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {

            if (!db.Subscriptions.Any(s => s.AdminSerial.Equals(db.Serials.Any())))
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Serials", action = "Create" }));
            }
            else
            {
                // Execute the Action method itself
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to put this `RequireSerial` custom authorize attribute on the top of action methods but nothing really happens.

```
[RequireSerial]
        public ViewResult Checkout()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override [OnAuthorization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.onauthorization(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorization(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext)) a `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` method. `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` is called by default implementation of `OnAuthorization` method if user is not authorized. 
Default implementation of `HandleUnauthorizedRequestredirects` the user to login page.

```
EFDbContext db = new EFDbContext();
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    //handle base authorization logic
    base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);     

    //if user is not authorized (by base rules) simply return because redirect was set in 'base.OnAuthorization' call.    
    if (this.AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext) == false)
    {
       return;
    }

    //Here comes your custom redirect logic:
    if (!db.Subscriptions.Any(s => s.AdminSerial.Equals(db.Serials.Any())))
    {
        filterContext.Result = your redirect url goes here;
    }                  
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

Authorization is basically a "boolean" value (not exactly a true boolean but it returns either an authorization or a failure of it)
to full get it this, MSDN's article about is very clear.

[Custom Authorization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707357(v=vs.91).aspx)

Comment: When you create a class for Custom Authorization, you need to override IsAuthorized function.